# How can I scan the following 2-D barcode using the AVFoundation framework in iOS 7?

Tags: ios7, avfoundation

I need to scan 2-D barcodes in iOS, like the following:

[image: This is a sample 2d barcode]

I tried the zbar framework but that didn't seem to work for these barcodes. Now I am trying to use the built-in AVFoundation framework in iOS 7. That works fantastically for 1-D barcodes whose AVObject type is AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, and QRCodes of type 
AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, but I am not able to scan 2D bar codes.

Is there any specific object type for 2D barcodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular type of 2-D barcode you're showing there is called a PDF417 barcode. AV Foundation also has the ability to scan those, as of iOS 7:

[image: PDF417 scanning example]

You need to use AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code to read the above, like in my image, for example by modifying Apple's QRchestra example with the following line:

```
[[self metadataOutput] setMetadataObjectTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, nil]];
```

and then logging the result to the screen like I did.

Comment: Thanks @Brad Larson, that works awesome, now i got an additional requirment i need to scan Data matrix barcodes too tried with all the Machine Readable Object Types but they dont seem to detect data matrix  you have any solution for this.. Thanks